# showing internal server issue while uploading a big file

Tags: php, upload

I am trying to upload one excel file by php code. If that excel file contains 200 records then it works fine. But if that excel file contains more than 500 records, then it shows `"Internal Server Error"` though I set the following:

```
set_time_limit(10000);
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '30M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '200M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 1000);
```

Also, in the file internally I am doing a lot, read data from excel file and store in an array then again checking from database whether any element is there in the database or not,. If so then remove that particular data. Again for the remaining data, inserting into a table and checking some conditions with for date. And finally with the remaining push in an array.
So is there any option to solve this internal server error issue? If so please let me know.

Code is like the following:

```
    <?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    set_time_limit(10000);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '30M');
    ini_set('post_max_size', '200M');
    ini_set('max_input_time', 1000);
    ?>
    <fieldset style="border:2px solid #60006B;">
      <legend >Upload Excel File</legend>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
           <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
           <table width="600">
             <tr>
                <td>Excel File:</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="cur_pic" style="border:1px solid #ccc;" /></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="padding-left:150px;"><input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" class="button" /></td>
             </tr>
            </table>
           </form>
        </fieldset>
<?php
  if(isset($_REQUEST['upload'])){
    $image =$_FILES["cur_pic"]["name"];
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['cur_pic']['tmp_name'];
    if ($image) {

      $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['cur_pic']['name']);

      $extension = getExtension($filename);
      $extension = strtolower($extension);

      if (($extension != "xls") && ($extension != "xlsx")) 
      {

        $change='<div class="msgdiv">Unknown file extension </div> ';
            $errors=1;
       }
       else
       {
         $size=filesize($_FILES['cur_pic']['tmp_name']); 
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cur_pic"]["tmp_name"],"sampleData/" . $_FILES["cur_pic"]["name"]);
        }
    }

   set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../../Classes/');

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
   include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
   $inputFileName = './sampleData/'.$_FILES["cur_pic"]["name"];
   echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory to  identify the format<br />';
   $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
   echo '<hr />';
   $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
   foreach($sheetData as $key => &$value) {
    if(is_array($value) && isset($value['A'])) $value = $value['A'];
   }
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT email,type FROM subscribe WHERE status='0'");
   $ultimate_array = array();
   while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
     if($res['type'] == '1'){
      if (in_array($res['email'], $sheetData)) {
    unset($sheetData[array_search($res['email'], $sheetData)]);
      }
     }
   } 

   $replace_string2 = array_unique($sheetData);

   $today_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

   foreach($replace_string2 as $ins_email){
    $chk_email = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM add_email WHERE email='".$ins_email."'"));
    if($chk_email == 0){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO add_email VALUES('','".$ins_email."','".$today_date."','1')");
    }
   }

   $final_email = array();
   foreach($replace_string2 as $f_email){
     $orig_sql = mysql_query("SELECT email,status FROM add_email WHERE email='".$f_email."'");
     while($res = mysql_fetch_array($orig_sql)){
        if($res['status'] == 1){
      array_push($final_email,$res['email']);       
        }
    else if($res['status'] == 0){
       $days = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT day FROM days"));
       $sql = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM add_email WHERE email='".$res['email']."' AND  DATEDIFF( NOW(),sending_date) > ".$days['day']);
       $no = mysql_num_rows($sql);
       if($no > 0){
        array_push($final_email,$f_email);  
           }    
         }
    }

     }

     $final_emails = array_unique($final_email);

     $_SESSION['record'] = $final_emails;

     foreach($final_emails as $ca){
    $ca_trim = trim($ca);
    mysql_query("UPDATE add_email SET sending_date='".$today_date."',status='0' WHERE email='".$ca_trim."'");
     }
            header('location:https://fgtpl.com/fugenx1/public_html/unsubscribe/Tests/14excel5.php');

}
```

Comment: The internal server error is a user friendly message. You should disable it in your browser to see the actual error message we can work with.

Answer (score 3):

You could check the disable_functions setting in your **php.ini** file. If this is shared hosting do

`<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` to check settings.

If shared hosting is a case i seriously doubt that you can do 200MB upload.

Comment: It is a dedicated server and in my case I am uploading an excel file of 28.4 kb. But in that file, it is containing 1119 records. I hope, in my code, so many loops are there for that it is happening. Shall I share my full code?

Comment: share just this upload part and put ini_set("display_errors", 1) at the top of upload page.

Comment: I have edited my code. Please see. I have added those processing code also which is creating the final array. Also I have added ini_set("display_errors", 1); but no error is showing.

Comment: For an information, sometime I am getting exact output, sometimes not after changing the line set_time_limit(1000); to set_time_limit(0);

Comment: Thanks a lot to all. I got the result. I just use indexng concept in my database. And it helps me to reach in my success.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your dedicated server you can do this:

1. Login into you server
2. If you are runing whm+cpanel on you server do this

   **tail -f /usr/local/apache/error.log**
   and then try upload. If errors occurs you will see here why
3. If you do not use whm+cpanel do this

   **tail -f /var/log/apache/error.log**
   and then try upload. If errors occurs you will see here why

In both cases you need to locate you apache error file. Paste output of your error for apache log file here.

Comment: Actually I am using windows, is there any option to see the error.log file from ftp. I purchased the server from godaddy.

Comment: Or maybe somehow you file is corrupted. Did you try uploading other files?

Comment: You should ask godaddy support on chat, where log file is located.

Comment: Ya I can upload other files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20569/discussion-between-sri-and-pregmatch)

Comment: Ya I got the solution. After using indexing in database table, it is working fine. Thanks for supporting to me.